# Использование списков DNSBL (RBL) для защиты web-сервера (apache) от злоумышлеников

Tags: веб-сервер, dns, apache2.4, спам

У меня в логах доступа к серверу за ночь всегда набирается куча записей с вредоносной активностью, при этом проверка их `IP` показывает, что они находятся в RBL-списках спамхауса.
Почему RBL-списки используются только для почтовых серверов?
Можно ли их использовать для блокировки доступа к веб-серверу, а то и к серверу в целом?
Я гуглил на эту тему, но но по RBL и DNSBL попадается только использование в почтовых серверах, при этом все эти вредоносные обращения могли бы блокироваться или апачем или `iptables`?
Чего я не понимаю или почему до сих пор нет возможности запрещать доступ к серверу, если клиент в `RBL`-списке?

Comment: Потому что в списках спамхауса находятся те адреса, которым **нельзя быть почтовыми серверами**. В их число входят IP-адреса простых пользователей, в том числе мой собственный IP. Забанив по спамхаусу, **вы забаните большинство простых пользователей и меня лично**.

Comment: Вы лучше скажите, почему вы решили, что активность вредоносная

Comment: @andreymal Попытка зайти по протоколу 1.0, попытка обратится к какому-то скрипты, попытка обратиться к скрытым директориям (.git .env), попытка найти админку, откровенный перебоор в попытке обнаружить pma или какой-то скрипт. И прочее. А некоторые представляются ботами, при этом предварительно даже к robots.txt обратится не удосуживаются. И все при проверке оказываются в списках спамхауса.

Comment: Во-первых, всё перечисленное вами является странной, но никак не вредоносной активностью. Во-вторых, как я уже ранее сказал, в спамхаус попадает ПОЧТИ ЛЮБОЙ обычный пользователь, в том числе и лично я.

Comment: 1 Странная - это когда пользователь случайно перешёл не туда или ввёл не то. Когда это разведка и попытка найти дуру - это вредоносная ИМХО!
2 У спамхауса есть разные списки. Общий список, используемый для почты, куда попадает DUHL (сети с динамическими адресами), я и не собираюсь использовать.
Но есть у него и отдельный список, куда попадают только зловреды, даже не спамеры, а именно зловреды. И именно в списках зловредов эти IP из логов оказываются, где потом детально можно прочитать когда и какая вредоносная активность за ним замечена.